# Managing local, dev and live versions of WordPress with Git

Tags: git, wordpress

I am looking at using git to manage version control for a WordPress project.

I typically have a local version, a development version on a web server that the client can access and test on and then a live version.

I will usually develop locally then push my changes to a repo on the server and then SSH into the dev folder on the server and pull from the repo. When I want to publish the changes on the live site I SSH into the live folder on the web server and pull from the repo.

Here is my dilemma.

I want the media added to the local version through the WordPress admin (image uploads etc) to be ignored but I want media added to the Dev version to be tracked so when I pull to the live site the media files from the dev site are pulled.

Any thoughts on the best way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be better solutions to this, but these two options have worked fine for me in similar situations.  Let's assume that the branch you work on locally is called `master` and in all your repositories the remote `origin` refers to the bare repository that you push to.

1. If all your media fall neatly into one directory, you can have a separate repository that tracks the media and add that as a [submodule](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#submodules) to the dev and live repositories.  In your local copy, you should either:

   - [in the situation where you want the live media locally] be careful not to (a) commit in your submodule, (b) push from it nor (c) add a new version of the submodule to your `master` branch
   - [in the situation where you don't need those media at all in your local copy] not update and initialize the submodule at all - just add its path to `.git/info/exclude`

   Even if your media are in various directories you could still use this method, but managing submodules is a bit of a pain, and gets rapidly more irritating if you have lots of them.
2. Alternatively, you can keep your dev and live repositories on a different branch, say called `with-media`, which is always the same as `master` but with commits that add the media at the end of the history.  You can maintain this situation with `git rebase`.  For example, if you've just made some changes locally that you want to push, you would do:

   ```
   git push origin master

   ssh server
   cd dev
   # git branch should show you that you're on 'with-media'
   git fetch origin
   git rebase origin/master
   ```

   Now suppose you upload some files to the dev repository, and want to commit them:

   ```
   ssh server
   cd dev
   git add [whatever-media-files]
   git commit
   git push origin with-media
   ```

   Now to update your live repository, you can just do:

   ```
   ssh server
   cd live
   # git branch should show that you're on 'with-media'
   git fetch origin
   git merge origin/with-media
   ```

   To set up those branches in the first place, you would do:

   ```
   ssh server
   cd dev
   # git branch should show that you're on 'master', since you haven't created
   # the other branch yet:
   git checkout -b with-media
   git push origin with-media

   cd ~/live
   git fetch origin
   git checkout -t origin/with-media
   ```

   As one last note, suppose you make some changes in the dev repository that aren't just adding media, and you want those code changes in your `master` branch.  Then (before you push anything!) you need to reorder the history with `git rebase -i origin/master`.

   ```
     ssh server
     cd dev
     git rebase -i origin/master
     # Reorder the lines so that the non-media commits are first (earliest) in the file.
     # Save the file and exit your editor.

     # Now find the SHA1 sum (object name) of the last commit that has non-media changes.
     # (The object name of the commits will have been changed by the rebase.)
     git log --oneline

     # Let's say that was commit f414f3l.  Then you can push just the history up to and
     # including that commit back to the master branch with:
     git push origin f414f3l:master

     # Also push your 'with-media' branch back:
     git push origin with-media
   ```

   In an ideal world you won't need to do those last steps often, but in practice it's good to know how to do that :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough explanation. This helps a great deal.